# ASP.NET Control.Font.Size units of measurement

Tags: asp.net, fonts, units-of-measurement

I need to set the Font.Size property in Points.
So normally I could set font-size:12pt in markup, but I need to switch the font size from the server side in code behind.

I set the lblText.Font.Size = 12 but the text is too small. What unit of measurement is used by default and how to convert it to points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

> lblText.Font.Size = new FontUnit(12, UnitType.Point);